# VS:Code - Full HTML Code completion in PHP Files

Tags: visual-studio-code

When i code an HTML File in VS:Code, it auto-closes my  Brackets and so on. Is it possible to make VSCode do that in php Files, too, within ?

Answer (score 0):

I think Emmet (extension) should serve the job.